# On Comodo Internet Security to restrict an application

Tags: windows-7, firewall, anti-virus, comodo-firewall

I've installed Comodo Internet Security a couple of days ago on Win 7 64bit Home Premium. One of the features is Defense+ and Auto-sandbox with specified level of restriction.

Recently I have downloaded two applications. I want to execute them in restricted environment. First thought was to run them as fully virtualized but then I realised the applications are sort of AddOns managers of one of my games. The addons themselves are only of a text type, not e.g. dlls etc. The applications have to have access to only one particular folder in "Program Files". Unfortunately, fully virtualized applications cannot save to any folder but the one specified in Sandbox Settings -> "Do not virtualize access to". I don't want to add anything else to "Do Not Virtualize this folders" because then all sandboxed applications would also have this access.

My question is if it's possible in Comodo Internet Security to turn on an access to a specific folder for a particular sandboxed application?

Hope my question makes sense :)